# how to handle home key/Events in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing game using iphone. When home screen button press, i want to make game is in pause mode. How to handle home screen button and events (`incoming and outgoing events`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {}` in you `AppDelegate.m`

Answer (score 0):

You don't handle the home button itself. However the UIApplicationDelegate (most likely in your AppDelegate.m) will receive a number of notifications

When entering the background (when you need to save):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

When user is coming back to your game:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

You look at the [UIApplicationDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to understand when each of these are called.